# Download Files from a http

Tags: c#, file, http, download

I am trying to download all the files from a start date to an end date from an http address. I managed to create a code that gets a file called "IMG_DK01IR1_yyyyMMddhhmm_004.bz2". The problem is that the date part looks only at dt_DLTime (201512180215), but I want all the files from dt_DLTime to dt. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
            DownloadLatestData();
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        public void DownloadLatestData()
        {

            DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;

            DateTime dt_DLTime = dt.Add(new TimeSpan(-35,0,-15,0));

            String m_DLTime = dt_DLTime.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm");


            textBox1.AppendText("Downloading for " + m_DLTime + "UTC" + Environment.NewLine);

            // create download string for JMV
            String m_DLStr_JMV_1 = "http://automet.fugrogeos.com:9090/pub/singapore";
            String m_DLStr_JMV = String.Concat(m_DLStr_JMV_1, "/IMG_DK01IR1_", m_DLTime, "_004.bz2");      
            String m_LocalFN_JMV = String.Concat(Application.StartupPath + "\\jmv\\IMG_DK01IR1_", m_DLTime, "_004.bz2");


            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile(m_DLStr_JMV, m_LocalFN_JMV);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // write a line of text to the file
                textBox1.AppendText(e.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            textBox1.AppendText("Finish downloading." + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to generate a list of date time strings in `yyyyMMddhhmm` format from a given start to a given end date, then use that list to generate the URLs to download

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach. The below code will try to identify all file links in your folder and then download them to your hard disk.

Once you know all the file names, it should be very easy to  filter by date time (if that's required).

Replace you `DownloadLatestData()` method's code with this code. I think your web server is not accessible to public. So the code is not tested.

```
       var webClient = new WebClient();
       const string baseUrl = @"http://automet.fugrogeos.com:9090/pub/singapore";
       const string diskPath = @"c:\MyFiles\";
       string content = webClient.DownloadString(baseUrl);
       var htmlLinks = content.Split(new[] {"</A>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       var paths = new List<string>();
       foreach (var htmlLink in htmlLinks)
       {
           var linkHrefs = htmlLink.Split(new[] { @"<A HREF=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
           foreach (var linkHref in linkHrefs.Where(h => h.ToLower().Contains(".bz2"))) 
           {
               var fileRefs = linkHref.Split(new[] {">"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               paths.Add(fileRefs[fileRefs.Length - 1]);
           }
       }

       foreach (var path in paths)
       {
          var bytes =  webClient.DownloadData(new Uri(baseUrl + path));
          File.WriteAllBytes(diskPath+ path, bytes);
       }
```